# PHP uploaded text file line breaks issue

Tags: php, post, text-files, line-breaks

I'm working on a simple script that get's a txt file posted to it and then displays the file contents. However, I'm having issues preserving line breaks.

It's being saved with windows notepad, which I think adds the CR LF for each line break, and then uploaded through a PHP form. I can echo the whole file contents but I need a way to split the data into new lines.

I've already tried to do `echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br />', $file);` and `nl2br($file)`. Neither worked.

I'm opening the file with `file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])'

Thanks.

Comment: Would using `<pre>(filecontents)</pre>` work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered reading the file into an array using the `file()` function in PHP?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Then you can output as needed, but each line will be in a single element of the array.

Comment: That works perfect actually, ultimately I need to separate by line then loop through all lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What works faster for me is to copy paste any text or Excel or HTML table type or newline type of data and paste it into a textarea instead of an inputextbox:

```
 <textarea  id="txtArea" name="txtArea" rows="40" cols="170"></textarea>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="split lines into array" />
```

in the form receiving file:

```
 $txtArea ='';  
 $txtArea = $_POST['txtArea'];  
 $TA = $_POST['txtArea'];  
 $string = $TA;  
 $array = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $string); 
// or any of these: 
// $array = explode(PHP_EOL,$string);  
// $array = explode("\n", $txtArea); 
 echo "<br>A0: ".$array[0];
 echo "<br>A1: ".@$array[1];
 echo "<br>A2: ".@$array[2];
```